# Kotlin generic methods and inheritance

Tags: android, generics, reactive-programming, rx-java, kotlin

In my code I would like to create a method in an abstract class, which returns some Observable. Then implementation of this abstract class would return Observable of certain (specified) type. Unfortunately Android Studio will return an error "Type mismatch" in implementation method():

- Expected: Observable
- Found: Observable<{package}.DrawerItemEntity>

My `MockDrawerList.getList()` returns `Observable<DrawerItemEntity>`

please focus on `execute()` and `buildUseCaseObservable`

### Abstract class

```
public abstract class UseCase(threadExecutor: ThreadExecutor,
    postExecutionThread: PostExecutionThread) {

    private val threadExecutor: ThreadExecutor
    private val postExecutionThread: PostExecutionThread

    private var subscription: Subscription = Subscriptions.empty()

    init {
        this.postExecutionThread = postExecutionThread
        this.threadExecutor = threadExecutor
    }

    protected abstract fun buildUseCaseObservable(): Observable<Any>

    public fun execute(useCaseSubsriber: Subscriber<Any>) {
        subscription = buildUseCaseObservable()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
                .observeOn(postExecutionThread.getScheduler())
                .subscribe(useCaseSubsriber)
    }

    public fun unsubsribe() {
        if (!subscription.isUnsubscribed())
            subscription.unsubscribe()
    }
}
```

### Implementation

```
Inject
class GetDrawerListUseCase(threadExecutor: ThreadExecutor, 
postExecutionThread:PostExecutionThread) : UseCase(threadExecutor, postExecutionThread) {

    override fun buildUseCaseObservable(): Observable<Any> {
        return MockDrawerList.getList()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `Observable` class in the implementation imported from the same package to the abstract class?

In Kotlin, type system lets you return, for example, `List<String>` as `List<Any>`, so the problem is, possibly, that the classes are different.

Comment: Every Observable I've used is imported from rx.Observable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though `String` is a subtype of `Any`, `Observable<String>` is *not* considered a subtype of `Observable<Any>` in Kotlin. You should use *use-site variance*: change `buildUseCaseObservable`'s return type to `Observable<out Any>` or `Observable<*>` (the latter is equivalent to `Observable<out Any?>`) and the code should compile.

Why doesn't inheritance for generic types work automatically based on their type parameters? This is a problem best explained by Joshua Bloch in Effective Java, Item 28: Use bounded wildcards to increase API flexibility. To put very simply, this can work only when the type is guaranteed not to consume instances of its type parameters, i.e. if a class with a generic parameter `T` has no methods taking `T` as a parameter. One way this can be enforced in Kotlin is by [declaration-site variance](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance), which is the case for example for collection interfaces (`kotlin.Collection`, `kotlin.List`, ...).

However, `Observable` is of course not a Kotlin class, so the compiler has no way of knowing that `Observable<String>` can be used safely where an `Observable<Any>` is expected. So we have to manually tell the compiler that we're OK with using only a subset of features of `Observable<T>` that don't take `T` as a parameter, so that we will get the nice inheritance instead. This "subset type" is called a [type projection](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections) in Kotlin and the technique is called use-site variance.

You can read more about declaration- and use-site variance in Kotlin in the official language documentation, section [Generics](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html).

Comment: I mark this as the answer for my question. However after this change I've got one more compiler error. This time caused by this line:  .subscribe(useCaseSubscriber) with error message: "Too many arguments for public final fun subscribe(): rx.Subscription! defined in rx.Observable". If I replace useCaseSubscriber with lambda, I have no access to method useCaseSubscriber.onNext() which should return type Any (in this case).

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the Kotlin type system. I've reported an issue here: [KT-8647](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8647). To workaround that, please cast the value explicitly to `Observable<Any>`. Basically what's happening is the compiler incorrectly identifies the subset of `Observable` I was talking about, deleting the `subscribe` method which takes a `Subscriber`.

Comment: The issue KT-8647 mentioned by @AlexanderUdalov has been marked "Fixed" in YouTrack, it should not longer be an issue.